# How to make validation optional for a complex type in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to display an editor for a type User.  User contains a field Address of type Address.  I made an editor template for the type Address so that it is reusable.

I don't want the field Address to be required for creating a user.  But some fields are required for Address, for example country, state etc.

I want to validate Address if I receive any data for it, if I don't receive anything, then I don't want to return any validation error to the UI for Address.  I would return only validation errors for User then.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using Data Annotations for validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into a Custom Model Binder for your User type.  That way you can choose  to override the validation of the Address item inside a User.

Answer (score 1):

I used some code from Simon J Ince of Microsoft. He has it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) on his blog. It also has client side validation which is also nice. It has a RequiredIf attribute that only makes a field required if another field has a certain value. Just being able to see how he implemented it helped me figure out how to do some of this stuff by myself and I even retrofitted it to allow multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that more complex custom validation is easier with [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).  The documentation provided is very helpful, and you will be able to achieve your validation goal with this open source validator.